# How to send data from radio buttons to Controller with Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have got an easy `HTML` page where I am displaying few `radio buttons`:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/processForm}" th:object="${priorities}"
  method="post">
  <fieldset>
    <table style="width: 500px">
      <tr th:each="item : ${chosen}">
        <td>
          <div>
            <div>
              <label th:text="${item}">example</label>
              <input type="radio" th:name="${'priorities[' + item + ']'}" value="a" />A
              <input type="radio" th:name="${'priorities[' + item + ']'}" value="b" />B
              <input type="radio" th:name="${'priorities[' + item + ']'}" value="c" />C
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button type="submit"
            class="btn btn-xs btn-primary margin10-right paddingNew"
            name="save">Calculate!</button>
        </td>
        <td></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Here you got what I can see:

[image: radios]

I would like to send this data to my controller, so I created one:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/processForm", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String save(@ModelAttribute(value = "foo") ClusterParams foo,
@ModelAttribute(value = "priorities") HashMap<String, String> priorities,
final ModelMap m) throws ClassNotFoundException, IOException,
InterruptedException {

    for (String s : priorities.keySet()) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Here you can see my class Weights (**removed**):

```
public class Weights {

    Map<String, String> priorities = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public Map<String, String> getPriorities() {
        return priorities;
    }

    public void setPriorities(Map<String, String> priorities) {
        this.priorities = priorities;
    }

}
```

but I have no idea how to set the values with thymeleaf.

I would like to get a mapping:

```
camera -> B
video -> C
```

Could you help me to do that? Of course it is my idea with creating a HashMap, if there is any other solution I will change it.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [6.4.1 Setting and getting basic and nested properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-beans-conventions), you should have `<input>` names such as `priorities[camera]` in generated HTML to make it work.

Try the following:

```
<input type="radio" th:name="${'priorities[' + item + ']'}" value="a" />
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. I changed my `html` page and my `controller` (I edited my post). I cannot see any output..I changed the names and everything looks well but it does not work. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your controller should take `Weights`, as before.